Redirect causing antiforgery issues when redirecting from ASP.NET Core MVC to ASP.NET MVC view
I'm doing an incremental upgrade from ASP.NET MVC to ASP.NET Core 8 MVC.
I have a page like MyCoreView. It has its own controller MyCoreController.
In the controller, there are 2 actions Index and Index(MyCoreViewModel model).
In the HttpPost Index endpoint, the code runs fine but then throws an error when using either return Redirect("/Legacy") or return RedirectToAction("Index", "Legacy"). When just returning the view there is no issue return View(model);
[Session]
[Authorize]
public class MyCoreController: Controller
{
    public MyCoreController()
    {
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        var model = new MyCoreViewModel ()
        {
            //... stuff here
        };

        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index(MyCoreViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //... Some code

            //return RedirectToAction("Index", "Legacy");
            return Redirect("/Legacy"); //return RedirectToAction("Index", "Legacy") also has same issue
        }

        return View(model);
    }
}

In my program.cs I have
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

As well as YARP reverse proxy config which is working for session and authentication sharing.
The logs I'm getting when trying to redirect is:
{
  "Depth": 0,
  "ClassName": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.AntiforgeryValidationException",
  "Message": "The antiforgery token could not be decrypted.",
  "Source": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery",
  "StackTraceString": "   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.DefaultAntiforgeryTokenSerializer.Deserialize(String serializedToken)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.DefaultAntiforgery.GetCookieTokenDoesNotThrow(HttpContext httpContext)",
  "RemoteStackTraceString": null,
  "RemoteStackIndex": 0,
  "HResult": -2146233088,
  "HelpURL": null
},
{
  "Depth": 1,
  "ClassName": "System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException",
  "Message": "The key {xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx} was not found in the key ring. For more information go to https://aka.ms/aspnet/dataprotectionwarning",
  "Source": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection",
  "StackTraceString": "   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.UnprotectCore(Byte[] protectedData, Boolean allowOperationsOnRevokedKeys, UnprotectStatus& status)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.Unprotect(Byte[] protectedData)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.DefaultAntiforgeryTokenSerializer.Deserialize(String serializedToken)",
  "RemoteStackTraceString": null,
  "RemoteStackIndex": 0,
  "HResult": -2146233087,
  "HelpURL": null
}

fields.ActionName: namespace.Controllers.MyCoreController.Index

Is there any way I can get the response to get the browser to redirect to the legacy views.
I have the redirect on the page click event which works fine
<a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Legacy")" >Go Back</a>


...are you using the same cookie-names with both applications? Or is ASP.NET Core trying to decrypt every cookie? (or every cookie with that magic prefix (which I forget...)) If so, that really won't work: ASP.NET 4 and ASP.NET Core have very incompatible security measures, even if they did use the same crypto keys, their settings for messaeg padding, concat, etc are different.

I have tried renaming the cookie to a different name and that had no effect

As shown in the log it is a data protection issue. Check if session consistent as you are using YARP. MVC and Core are different framework so based on my research it won't pass the auth in such case. You could check this for some details https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/compatibility/replacing-machinekey?view=aspnetcore-8.0
